Prove maximum of $p\cdot(1-p)^{n-1}$ is at $p=\frac{1}{n}$ without differentiation
I would like to do a proof with my high school students that for $0\le p\le 1$, the maximum of $p\cdot(1-p)^{n-1}$ is reached for $p=\frac{1}{n}$. Proving this with differentiation is quite trivial, however my students don't have access to that tool. Is there an other/easier way to prove this without differentiation?
(Context: CS class, simple wireless networking protocol, in which each participant transmits a message with probability p. How can we maximize message throughput, given that transmissions of multiple messages at the same time results in collisions, i.e., the messages can only be transmitted one at a time?)

I suppose that what you mean is that the maximum is located at $\frac1n$.

@JoséCarlosSantos thanks for pointing that out, I have reworded the question accordingly

This might help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Quoting Wikipedia: if the probability of success on each trial is $p$, then the probability that the $n$-th trial is the first success is exactly $p\cdot(1-p)^{n-1}$. This is not a proof but maybe it can help your students understand the problem more: it is very intuitive that the "ideal" probability for the first success to happen at the $n$-th trial should be the one that makes every trial equally likely to succeed

For an elementary proof, one may use the following inequality:
$$
a_1 \cdots a_n \le \left( \frac{a_1 + \cdots + a_n}{n} \right)^n,
$$
in which $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, and the "$=$" holds iff $ a_1 = \cdots = a_n $.
Since $0 \le p \le 1$, we know that $p, 1 - p \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$. Notice that:
$$
\begin{align*}
 p (1 - p)^{n - 1} 
 = & \
 \frac{1}{n - 1} (n - 1)p \cdot \underbrace{(1 - p) \cdots (1 - p)}_{n - 1 \text{ copies }} \\
 \le & \
 \frac{1}{n - 1} \left( \frac{ (n - 1) p + (n - 1) (1 - p) }{ n } \right)^{n} \\
 = & \
 \frac{1}{n - 1} \left( \frac{n - 1}{n} \right)^n,
\end{align*}
$$
the "$ = $" holds iff $ (n - 1)p = 1 - p $, that is, $ p = 1 / n $.

The only difficulty with this approach (which is the one I would go to as well) is how to motivate the generic AM-GM inequality. This is certainly doable but does present some challenge.

Here is not a complete proof, but it would get even messier to show the rest is positive.
It is the same as maximizing $k(n-k)^{n-1}$ at $k=1$.
Show that $(n-1)^{n-1}-k(n-k)^{n-1}$ has a double zero at $k=1$, hence a local min there.
$$(n-1)^{n-1}-k(n-k)^{n-1}\\=(n-1)^{n-1}-(n-k)^{n-1}-(k-1)(n-k)^{n-1}\\
=(k-1)\left[(n-1)^{n-2}+(n-1)^{n-3}(n-k)+\cdots+(n-k)^{n-2}-(n-k)^{n-1}\right]$$
When $k=1$, the factor inside the square brackets  comes to zero, so there must be another factor of $k-1$.
EDiT
I think the expression is
$$(k-1)^2\left[1(n-1)^{n-3}+2(n-1)^{n-4}(n-k)+3(n-1)^{n-5}(n-k)^2+\cdots+(n-2)(n-k)^{n-3}\right]$$

Under the constraints of the problem, one can further restrict attention to $k\in[0,n]$.

In the final expression, it helps to replace $k-1$ with $(n-1)-(n-k)$.
